# Exponential of a symmetric 2-tridiagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, matrix-exponential, tridiagonal-matrices

Is there any way of computing analytically the exponential (or finding the eigenvalues, or determining if it's positive definite) of a $n\times n$ symmetric 2-tridiagonal matrix:
$$
T_n^{(2)}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & 0 & b_1 &  & & \\
    0 & a_2 & 0 & b_2 &  & \\
    b_1 & 0 & a_3 & 0 & b_3 & \\
     & b_2 & 0 & a_4 & 0 & \ddots &\\
     &  & b_3 & 0 & a_5 & \ddots & b_{n-2}\\
     & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
     & & & & b_{n-2} & 0 & a_n
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Actually I am interested only on the first and the second row of the $\exp[T_n^{(2)}]$, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial result: If you permute the indices of this matrix as $$\{1,2,3,4,\cdots\}\mapsto\{1,3,5,\cdots,2,4,6,\cdots\}$$ then the matrix becomes block diagonal

$$T_n^{(2)}=\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
    a_1 & b_1 & 0&\cdots &  \\
    b_1 & a_3 & b_3 & \cdots &  & \ddots \\    
    0 & b_3 & a_5 & \cdots &  & & \ddots\\
    \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ddots \\ \hline
    & &&& a_2 & b_2 & 0&\cdots   \\
    &\ddots&&& b_2 & a_4 & b_4 & \cdots &  & \\    
    &&\ddots&& 0 & b_4 & a_6 & \cdots &  & \\
   &&&&  \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ddots
  \end{array}\right)$$ i.e. $T_n^{(2)}$ is the direct sum of two submatrices $\mathcal{O}_{n},$ $\mathcal{E}_n$. This converts the question from being about a single 2-tridiagonal matrix to a pair of standard 1-tridiagonal matrices. For instance, since $T_n^{(2)}=\mathcal{O}_{n}\oplus\mathcal{E}_n$ we have $\exp T_n^{(2)}=(\exp \mathcal{O}_{n})\oplus (\exp \mathcal{E}_{n}).$ There's an extensive amount of literature on such tridagonal matrices, so I won't attempt to cover it here.